# Quick script for joining bmesh verts; Only last operation is performed

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode, vertices, bmesh

So I built a simple script to take a set of selected verts, mark the most recently selected as target and connect all other verts to target with bmesh.ops.connect_verts

```
import bpy
import bmesh

sel = bpy.context.active_object

if sel.mode == 'EDIT':
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(sel.data)  
    verts = bm.select_history
    target = verts[-1]
    for v in range(0, len(verts)-1):
        bmesh.ops.connect_verts(bm, verts=[verts[v],target])
    
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(sel.data)
```

So I have something like this:

[image]

When I run my code it only seems to connect the second to last selection with the target

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wait, what? You are trying to connect vertexes without making faces between them?

Comment: All the verts are connected by an ngon, my goal is basically to triangulate the ngon based on the active vert instead of just an auto triangulation.

Comment: Yes, but if you will add edges like this you will end up with the same N-gon and a bunch of edges connected to vertexes, but not divining the N-gon.

Comment: How do you recommend I achieve this?

Comment: One think I've just found: there's a bug in select_history.  If you select by using CTRL-LMB to include all of the vertices between the starting point and the vertex you're clicking on it only records the vertex you're clicking on and not all of the others.  You need to find the selected vertices by another means.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thank you! Just did some debugging and found this to be the issue. Found the solution to be adding `verts = [vert for vert in bm.verts if vert.select]` and then popping with `verts.pop(verts.index(target))` Gives me a list of selected verts without the target.